# Сородица. Есть такое слово?

Tags: лексика, словообразование

О мужчине говорят "сородич", а для слова женского рода можно так трансформировать — **сородица**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такое слово — ***сородица***, нашлось в [**латинско-праславянском словаре**](http://www.tezan.ru/slov_lat_3.htm).

Латинское слово — **soror**;
классический перевод — **сестра**;
праславянское слово в латинском написании — **so-rdnj**;
перевод с праславянского — сородная, **сородица**.

Встретилось это слово и в таком предложении:
*Дикая среднеазиатская **сородица** лошади.*

[**сородич**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/145189), -а; *м.*
**1.** Член одного с кем-либо рода в родовом обществе. **//** Разг. = **Ро́дственник.**
*На юбилей собрались все сородичи.*
**/** О животных, растениях одного вида. *Дикие сородичи домашней кошки.*

В словаре синонимов В. Н. Тришина (2013) к слову [**родственница**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/154823/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) имеются такие синонимы:
брательница, единокровница, родня, свойственница, сокровница, **сородичка, сродница, сродственница**, южика.

*Почуяв холодный воздух, маленькая **сородичка** великих драконов — несравненно меньшая, но такая же царапучая и агрессивная — недовольно пискнула.*
В. Иващенко. Маленькая ведьма

Answer (score 1):

У ***сородича*** —

> м. устар. 1. Человек одного с кем либо рода (при первобытно общинном
>   строе). 2. Человек близкого, родственного с кем либо происхождения,
>   принадлежащий к одной с кем либо народности, национальности или
>   происходящий из одной с кем либо местности

— пары, похоже нет. Есть синонимичные *родственница*, *землячка*.

Есть пара к ***сроднику*** —

> м. разг. сниж. то же, что родственник

— *сродница*, -ы, ж. Устар. и прост. Женск. к *сродник*: «*А кто она тебе? баба или сродница?*»

Comment: Наверно, Вы имели в виду **родственница**?

Comment: Спасибо. Конец трудовой недели.